# Python time counter

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have data coming in from an outside source (serial port in this case) roughly every 2.5 seconds.
I want to store ( in mysql) a sample of this data every 5 minutes, not every 2.5 seconds.
How would i implement this in python?
One can probably not use a sleep function since this will stop the rest of the script.

Comment: Use the `time` module or if you know the 2.5 and can re-use that it would be every 120 times would be 5 mins, keep a counter and modulus 120 then store your sample.

Comment: Why don't you keep track of when did you last take the sample with a datetime.datetime object, and if datetime.datetime.now() is >= 5 minutes higher than the stored value,  take a sample...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check how much time has passed since the last save for each incoming event, and update the last-save timestamp after each save:

```
import time
lastsave = 0
def SaveEvent(data):
    # do what you need to save it
    ...


# I'm assuming there's some sort of event loop that 
# detects new events and directs them to some HandleEvent function

def HandleEvent(data):
    global lastsave
    if time.time() - lastsave > 300: 
    # this is in seconds, so 5 minutes = 300 seconds
        lastsave = time.time()
        SaveEvent(data)
```

If your application is multithreaded or multiprocessing you should also look into implementing a lock in the `SaveEvent` function to avoid concurrent saves.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `Timer` class from `threading` - something like.

```
import time
from threading import Timer

def poll_port():
    print "Getting my data from port", time.time()

def main():
    print "Main:enter", time.time()
    while True:
        t = Timer(5, poll_port)
        t.start()
        t.join()
        print "after join:", time.time()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example output:

```
Main:enter 1359755186.87
Getting my data from port 1359755191.88
after join: 1359755191.88
Getting my data from port 1359755196.88
after join: 1359755196.88
Getting my data from port 1359755201.88
after join: 1359755201.88
Getting my data from port 1359755206.88
```